# Print Div Content without Using JavaScript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

Hi every one is there any way to Print `Div` Content without Using JavaScript in asp.net web application.
Thank you all

Comment: Print when and where?

Comment: Print specific part of web page in ASP.Net to printer when user click print

Comment: @NicoSchertler I don't want to use JavaScript for it .. any suggestion thanx

Comment: Use an appropriate CSS stylesheet with media queries for printers.

Comment: @NicoSchertler any example for that ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120645/discussion-between-farooq-alsaegh-and-nico-schertler).